# Why do social networking sites such as Facebook, Google+ and Twitter not support posting iframes

Tags: facebook, iframe, twitter, google-plus

Sometimes, when you would like to publish a video, an audio item, a widget, etc., on your website, you're provided with code between `<iframe>` and `</iframe>` which you can copy into your website.

I thought it would be really cool if social networks such as Facebook, Google Plus and Twitter allowed us to post such code in our posts, status updates and tweets.

I'm not seeing this happen and I don't understand why?!?

Does anyone know?

---

UPDATE: Because an iframe can't contain anything that you couldn't post on a web page, I didn't think there would be any security issues. It's really sad that the BIG players are so closed minded. We could do lots of interesting things if they weren't so eager to control everything: for example sharing widgets of 3D products we could print and which may be found on http://www.shapeways.com/featured?li=nav or elsewhere. I find that we're being limited right now, because the BIG players are so busy creating proprietary silos, each one having his own app store and proprietary data formats. Personally, I'm all for open source software and open data we can all share and experience without being locked-in. There seems to be no shared vision for an integrated www where html pages representing widgets may be embedded inside other html pages. This would also be interesting in the field of data visualisation as the widget could be built on javascript frameworks such as those listed here: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/  The www would undoubtedly be a lot richer and more interesting. IMHO the web shouldn't belong to any few major companies, because we ALL make the web what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that these sites do not want you to be able to display anything that you want on their real estate. There are also security concerns in some situations, such as embeddeding something that looks like a log in form, but is really a phishing attack or other issues with it seeming to appear like legitimate content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brett. We badly need a neutral standards supportive social network.